# content not staying in a circle div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am unable to keep my content in my div that is a circle. The html jumps out of its container and tries to align itself to what the image is inside it. Any ideas on how to keep it in there? I am using Google Chrome.

Thank you in advance!

Love knowing I can come here and ask my 500 closest online friends for help.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="logo">
    <div style="padding-top: 3%;">
        <p class="RST" data-height="50" style="line-height: 90%;">welcome</p>
        <p  class="RST" data-height="50" style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 90%">manager</p>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="square teal" style="width: 50%; height: 27.5%; float:left;">
        <img src="img/dollar.png"/>
        <p class="RST" data-height="20";>rent<br>managment</p>
    </div>

    <div class="square lightGreen" style="width: 50%; height: 27.5%; float:right;">
        <img src="img/tenant.png"/>
        <p class="RST" data-height="20";>tenant<br>managment</p>
    </div>


    <div class="square lightGreen" style="width: 50%; height: 27.5%; float:left;">
        <img src="img/wrench.png"/>
        <p class="RST" data-height="20";>manage<br>managment</p>
    </div>

    <div class="square teal" style="width: 50%; height: 27.5%; float:right;">
        <img src="img/pages.png"/>
        <p class="RST" data-height="20";>contract<br>managment</p>
    </div>

<div class="circle">
    <p>center<br>picture</p>
</div>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#mainWrapper{
    background-image: url('../img/wheat.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 32%;
    right: 32%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 466.2px;
}

.logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    color: #4a9682;
}

.logo img{
    height: 95%;
}

.logoP{
    line-height: .8;
}

.generalBox{
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.generalBox img{
    height: 75%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.generalBox p{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 1%;
}

.square{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.square img{
    height: 60%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle{
    background-image: url('../img/nial.png');
    width: 20%;
    height: 22.5%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top:23%;
    left: 40%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.circle p{
    font-size: 10px;
    display: inline-block;       
}

/****************************************
 Colors
*****************************************/
.teal{background-color:rgba(82,131,158,0.9);}
.purple{background-color:rgba(113,141,197,0.9);}
.lightBlue{background-color:rgba(140,220,239,0.9);}
.darkGreen{background-color:rgba(109,179,175,0.9);}
.lightGreen{background-color:rgba(76,201,182,0.9);}
.

.signUp{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;

}
```

Comment: you should post relevant HTML markup and CSS code here in the question

Comment: what browser are you using? works fine in Safari and Firefox. Also, post your code otherwise how are we supposed to help? My initial guess is that the browser you're using doesn't have support for CSS3 border-radius...have you tried cross-browser vendor-prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/change the following property values.

```
.circle{
 display: table;
}

.circle p{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```